# Use number field as date in Kibana date_histogram aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, aggregation

I'm trying to use Visualize feature in Kibana to plot monthly date_histogram graph that counts # of messages in my system. Message type has a `sent_at` field that is stored as `number` since epoch time.
Although I can do that just fine with elasticsearch query

```
POST /_all/message/_search?size=0
{
    "aggs" : {
        "monthly_message" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "sent_at",
                "interval" : "month"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I ran into a problem in Kibana saying `No Compatible Fields: The "myindex" index pattern does not contain any of the following field types: date`

Is there a way to get Kibana to use `number` field as date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to my knowledge, Kibana will use the index mapping in order to find out date fields, if no date fields can be found, then Kibana won't be able to infer one from the other number fields.

What you can do is to add another field called `sent_at_date` to your mapping, then use the update-by-query API in order to copy the `sent_at` field to that new field and finally to recreate your index pattern in Kibana.

It goes basically like this:

```
# 1. add a new field to your mapping
PUT myindex/_mapping/message
{
   "properties": {
      "sent_at_date": {
         "type": "date"
      }
   }
}

# 2. update all your documents
POST myindex/_update_by_query
{
   "script": {
      "source": "ctx._source.sent_at_date = ctx._source.sent_at"
   }
}
```

And finally recreate your index pattern in Kibana. You should see a new field called `sent_at_date` of type `date` that you can use in Kibana.